# what is the right code for $_REQUEST['$num']

Tags: php, arrays, request

Good day.I just to ask what is the right code for this

**exam.php**

```
<form action="score.php" method="post" name="submit">
<?php

    while($ar=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $num=$ar['num'];
        $a=$ar['a'];
        $b=$ar['b'];
        echo "<br>  <input type='radio' name='q$num' value='$a'>$a"; 
        echo "<br>  <input type='radio' name='q$num' value='$b'>$b";           
}       
?>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

here is the problem
**score.php**

how can i get those values on this page
I've tried to use

```
$ans=$_REQUEST['$x'];
```

but it's not working..Please help me.Thank You

Comment: You want to share variable in two different scripts? (php programs) ?

Comment: What is $x by the way. Try printing your POST array. print_r($_POST);

Comment: i used $x to name my radio button.the '' are my only problem,thanks to lkac when i removed those it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if is submit presed

```
if ((isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
    ///
}
```

And use like this : `$ans=$_REQUEST[$x]; // no ' '`